# Example of using AntiXssEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode from System.Web.Security?

Tags: asp.net, xss

I need to use AntiXssEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode from System.Web.Security in an ASP.NET application and have been looking for an example of its use.

The Microsoft has incorporated parts of their AntiXss Library into the .NET framework (but not the overload that returns an an HtmlAttributeEncoded string). The documentation shows only one method with no overloads:

protected internal override void HtmlAttributeEncode (string value, System.IO.TextWriter output);

The obvious way to use it is to define a subclass of AntiXSSEncoder and use a StringWriter to hold the encoded text string so it can be returned.

This seems like an expensive (in terms of complexity and processor usage) way to use the encoder.

Does anyone have a better way to use the method? If so would you be willing to provide a code snippet?

Thanks

Mike